# What did the last text say at the end of The Fosters S01E13

Tags: dialogue, the-fosters

In the episode "Things Unsaid" (S01E13) of The Fosters, Cole replied to Brandon's text from Callie's phone. But the episode cut off before I could read what the text said, and I can't figure out the right terms to google this. Can someone please tell me what it said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Later, Stef and Lena go to bed, but Lena can’t sleep. Brandon texts Callie, then receives a text back telling him things are over between them. He has no idea that Cole sent the message.

By the way, the search term I used was "The Fosters Season 1 Episode 13 last text"